# FloatingActionsButtons equally distributed to full width

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I would like to evenly distribute 6 buttons over the whole width, so they have all the same space between.
AndroidStudio Design looks like this:

[image]

But on my device it looks like this :

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

**LinearLayout:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_buttons_timeline"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_previous_timeline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription=""
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/fab_size"
        app:maxImageSize="@dimen/fab_image_max_size"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_previous"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_bookmark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/fab_size"
        app:maxImageSize="@dimen/fab_image_max_size"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainmenubookmark_de"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_search_timeline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/fab_size"
        app:maxImageSize="@dimen/fab_image_max_size"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainmenubookmark_de"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_map"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/fab_size"
        app:maxImageSize="@dimen/fab_image_max_size"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainmenubookmark_de"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_calendar_timeline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/fab_size"
        app:maxImageSize="@dimen/fab_image_max_size"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainmenubookmark_de"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_next_timeline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/fab_size"
        app:maxImageSize="@dimen/fab_image_max_size"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainmenubookmark_de"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Dimens.xml:

10dp
40dp
40dp
24dp

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you also share LinearLayout content.

I also recommend using ConstraintLayout for this, it's definitely easier and fun.

Comment: Thanks, First, fill_parent has been deprecated. Can you replace it with match_parent.

Also, are we sure that the outer structure surrounding this code will not cause such a restriction?